# Applying condition based on a list and create a new column based on the outcome r

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a list as follows:

```
c1 <-("apple", "tree", "husband")
```

and this data:

```
df <-data.frame(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  col = c("husband", "apple", "juice", "happy", "husband", "white"),
)
```

and I want to have this output:

```
df <-data.frame(
  ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
  col = c("husband", "apple", "juice", "happy", "husband", "white"),
  c1 = c("1","1","0","0","1","0")
)
```

by applying the list (c1) as a condition and **not** to use

```
mutate(c1= ifelse(col==happy | col==tree | col==husband,1,0))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%in%` to check `c1` values in `col`

```
transform(df, c1 = as.integer(col %in% c1))
#Even shorter
#transform(df, c1 = +(col %in% c1))

#  ID     col c1
#1  b husband  1
#2  b   apple  1
#3  b   juice  0
#4  a   happy  0
#5  a husband  1
#6  c   white  0
```

Using `as.integer` over logical values is faster way than using `ifelse` :

```
transform(df, c1 = ifelse(col %in% c1, 1, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `grepl()` to check any of the values in `c1` and assign directly to a new variable:

```
#Data 1
c1 <- c("apple", "tree", "husband")
#Data 2
df <-data.frame(
    ID = c("b","b","b","a","a","c"),
    col = c("husband", "apple", "juice", "happy", "husband", "white"),stringsAsFactors = F)
#Match and create new variable
df$NewVar <- as.numeric(grepl(paste0(c1,collapse = '|'),df$col))
```

Output:

```
  ID     col NewVar
1  b husband      1
2  b   apple      1
3  b   juice      0
4  a   happy      0
5  a husband      1
6  c   white      0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play a trick via `factor`, e.g.,

```
within(df, out <- +!is.na(factor(col,levels = c1)))
```

or via `%in%`

```
within(df, out <- +(col %in%c1))
```

or via `match`

```
within(df,out <- 1-is.na(match(col,c1)))
```

such that

```
  ID     col out
1  b husband   1
2  b   apple   1
3  b   juice   0
4  a   happy   0
5  a husband   1
6  c   white   0
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     mutate(c1 = case_when(col %in% c1, 1, 0))
```

---

Or another option is

```
df %>%
    mutate(c1 = +(col %in% c1))
```